# Return multiple rows from matching on multiple CASE matches?

Tags: case

I want to add a column to my query which will specify one or more categories a row matches. I want to take this:

```
    +--------------+---------------+
Row | Product      | Quantity_Sold |
    +--------------+---------------+
1   | Coca-Cola    | 15            |
2   | Cigarettes   | 4             |
3   | Pretzel      | 6             |
4   | Beer         | 25            |
5   | Popcorn      | 10            |
6   | Candy Bar    | 10            |
    +--------------+---------------+
```

And return this:

```
    +--------------+---------------+----------------------+
Row | Product      | Quantity_Sold | Category             |
    +--------------+---------------+----------------------+
1   | Coca-Cola    | 15            | Beverages            |
2   | Cigarettes   | 4             | Controlled Substance |
3   | Pretzel      | 6             | Snacks               |
4   | Beer         | 25            | Beverages            |
5   | Beer         | 25            | Controlled Substance |
6   | Popcorn      | 10            | Snacks               |
7   | Candy Bar    | 10            | Snacks               |
    +--------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

Notice on line 4-5 of the output, "Beer" is on two lines, because it fits in two categories.

If I try to do this with CASE, only the *first* match will be counted.

This query

```
SELECT
    Product,
    Quantity_Sold,
    CASE
        WHEN
            Product IN ('Coca-Cola', 'Beer')
        THEN
            'Beverages'
    CASE
        WHEN
            Product IN ('Pretzel', 'Popcorn', 'Candy Bar')
        THEN
            'Snacks'
    CASE
        WHEN
            Product IN ('Cigarettes', 'Beer')
        THEN
            'Controlled Substance'
    END
        AS Category
FROM sales_table;
```

Would only return this output

```
    +--------------+---------------+----------------------+
Row | Product      | Quantity_Sold | Category             |
    +--------------+---------------+----------------------+
1   | Coca-Cola    | 15            | Beverages            |
2   | Cigarettes   | 4             | Controlled Substance |
3   | Pretzel      | 6             | Snacks               |
4   | Beer         | 25            | Beverages            |
5   | Popcorn      | 10            | Snacks               |
6   | Candy Bar    | 10            | Snacks               |
    +--------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

(Notice "Beer" only appears once)

So how can I get it to show up on separate lines for all categories it matches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A join would be the best solution here.

Create a table that contains a list of categories and which products are associated with them, something like Product, Category we'll call it ProductCategories. Then join on this table.

```
SELECT p.Product, p.Quantity_Sold, pc.Category
FROM sales_table p
JOIN ProductCategories pc ON pc.Product = p.Product'
```

This has the added benefit of not having to modify your case statement as you add more categories (which quickly gets difficult/impossible to maintain), and only requires a simple insert into the new table.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a simple way to get each match to show up on a separate row. I don't have any write access to this system, so could I create the "ProductCategories" table on-the-fly so I can use it for this join?

I was using CASE because it was rather simple to include in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @NathanC.Lee: It depends on the database engine you are using. In MSSQL 2008 or later you can use the "values" virtual table constructor - see https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/ for examples. Similar syntax is available elsewhere to. In MSSQL 2005 and some other systems you don't have the extended `values` syntax but can construct a virtual table similarly using unioned selects as a subquery or CTE.

Comment: If you wanted, you could join on what would effectively be a temp table, although I would highly recommend making this an actual table, as it will be easier to add to/expand and reuse later.

Comment: @DavidSpillett I'm on Oracle - I don't think I have anything like that. Too bad.

Comment: @Sethcran I fully agree - but I don't have any write access.

Comment: @NathanC.Lee: I'm pretty sure Oracle has supported CTEs for some time (not 100% sure as I don't use Oracle) and it definitely supports the sub-query option so you could do something like: `SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> AS a JOIN (SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS relID UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID) AS b ON b.relID=a.ID`

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't create a permanent table you could use a CTE and a join.

```
WITH Category (Product,Category) AS
    (SELECT 'Coca-Cola','Beverages'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Beer','Beverages'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pretzel','Snacks'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Popcorn','Snacks'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Candy Bar','Snacks'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Cigarettes','Controlled Substance'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Beer','Controlled Substance'
        )
SELECT
    sales_table.Product,
    Quantity_Sold,
    Category.Category
FROM sales_table
JOIN Category
    ON sales_table.Product = Category.Product;
```

Comment: Excellent. That didn't quite work as you posted it. I got an "unsupported column aliasing" error. I think it doesn't like the columns being defined in the WITH line, and it yelled at me about not having a FROM with each select, so I had it use "FROM dual", which is some goofy fake table Oracle keeps around for times such as these.

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't realize you were using Oracle when I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Sethcran and Kenneth Fisher, for each providing parts of this answer. I found the last missing piece here: [Oracle create table using with clause (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429393/oracle-create-table-using-with-clause)

Here's what eventually worked:

```
WITH Category AS
    (SELECT 'Coca-Cola' AS Product,'Beverages' AS Category
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Beer','Beverages'
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pretzel','Snacks'
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Popcorn','Snacks'
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Candy Bar','Snacks'
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Cigarettes','Controlled Substance'
        FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Beer','Controlled Substance'
        FROM dual
    )
SELECT
    sales_table.Product,
    sales_table.Quantity_Sold,
    Category.Category
FROM sales_table
JOIN Category
    ON sales_table.Product = Category.Product;
```